# How to chain multiple tasks with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some async tasks to do, like task1, task2, task3, ..., and their relationships is like the graph below.

[image]

This is a directed acyclic graph so I can use topological sorting to figure out one possible execution route.

But it is still non trivial task for human, maybe like this.

```
task7.start().done(check_if_5_is_done_then_start_11, check_if_3_is_done_then_start_8);
task5.start().done(check_if_7_is_done_then_start_11);
task3.start().done(check_if_7_is_doen_then_start_8, check_if_11_is_doen_then_start_10);

....
```

I'd prefer a more elegant solution, like:

```
var Tasks = new Tasks({
  task7:  [func7,  []],
  task11: [func11, ["task7", "task5"]],
  task5:  [func5, []],
  task8:  [func8, ["task3"]]
  ...
});

Tasks.start().alldone(function () { // done  });
```

Comment: take a look at q https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @vinayr Well, I gave a quick glance at that, it seems I should use the `.all()` method, would you please post some examples?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pretty much exactly the use case [async.auto](https://github.com/caolan/async#autotasks-callback) is designed for.

Comment: And have a look at `async` in general, its quite epic.